# Ubuntu login passwords button [doesn't change the outline color]

Tags: ubuntu

My system's color now is cyan but the login password button still orange in the outline (like default)
I'm a new to Ubuntu, thanks for your helps.
[I have changed Ubuntu default color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWWxC.png)

I have tried to change it by Gnome Tweaks but nothing change.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ is the correct website to ask Ubuntu related questions.